# Cannot find module (ts-jest)

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

guys, I have a problem testing my TypeScript code with ts-jest. The issue is that when I import module using no extension it is no problem:

`import {Calculus, Course, DesignPatterns, MachineLearning} from "./Course";`

But when I do the same with '.js' extension (I need it for my HTML code (that includes translated into JS from TS) working):

`import {Calculus, Course, DesignPatterns, MachineLearning} from "./Course.js";`

i have the error "Cannot find module './Course.js' from 'src/classes/Administration.ts'"

Whole importing code is, but jest don`t like only the last line:

```
import PersonalInfo from '../lab2classes/PersonalInfo.js'
import {Professor} from '../lab2classes/Staff.js'
import Group from './Group.js';
import {Calculus, Course, DesignPatterns, MachineLearning} from './Course.js';
```

Whole src/ directory looks like:

```
src/
 classes/
  Administration.ts
  Course.ts 
  Group.ts
 lab2classes/
  Course.ts (yeah, it is not a typo)
  Enrollment.ts
  Seminar.ts
  PersonalInfo.ts
  Staff.ts
 App.ts
 objects.ts
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be import {Calculus, Course, DesignPatterns, MachineLearning} from '../lab2classes/Course.ts'; ? Because Administration is in the classes directory

Comment: nah, Course.ts from classes/ and Course.ts from lab2classes/ are different - I need the first one